# Advice for removing external fibre-cement cladding (Hardie Board) to inspect window-leak damage

Tags: walls

I bought a place with a long-term window leak. I want to remove an outside fibre-cement panel (Hardie Board) and have a look behind it to assess the damage.

I was hoping someone could give some advice about removing the panels properly. In particular, how to remove the joins. How are they fastened?

I have a photo with the panel I want to remove:

[image: wall panel under window]

And here's a close-up of the top of the joint:

[image: detail of the joint between panels]

Thanks.

Comment: Is inspection from inside an option? Matching that texture to fix any damage looks like a pain.

Comment: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcJiXlUK90Q) | [PDF](https://www.jameshardiepros.com/getattachment/7a796322-f37f-4c83-8ebb-fd06673eb3a8/hardiepanel-commercial-hz5-us-en.pdf) I'll admit that I'm unfamiliar with what looks like fibercement battens on your home. Are you sure it's Hardie?

Comment: @popham Unfortunately not! Other side is kitchen cabinetry that I don't want to mess with. Did a bit of research about using special rollers to reproduce the texture but agree it'll be a pain. House wrap is right behind the cladding, so I'll have to cut into that too.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not sure. It's in Australia ~2000 build. I'd say it's an outdated James Hardie product. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Um, don't? *How to remove the joins. How are they fastened?* Absolutely no clue +1. *to assess the damage* do you really want to know anyway? Kitchen cabinet isn't trying to fall through the floor? (sign of the cross) I dub thee Caulk Man. Vulkem is good. But there's this stuff that comes in a bag that we use on our solarium. I'd have to look what it is. - Objective is the window not leaking. - Do every window.

Comment: And when I say caulk it, I mean caulk the @#%! out of it. In that close up pic, there will be (like two inches of) caulk all the way up to halfway between that screw and the top of the picture, leading to a fillet that sheds water all the way to the outside corner of that channel, *and then some*, for an attempt at a drip edge. Then do the top and the sides. Then assume all other windows are or will be like this; do all of them, everywhere. - And the doors... and any other penetrations. Or you can borrow my 10' pole to mess with *stucco on steroids*.

Comment: Looks like they used a sawsall to replace the window and then didn't put back the piece of channel that used to be there and still should. Put a piece of 1/2"x 2"(?) aluminum u-channel and it wouldn't need to be (*showing*) such a caulk mess (still should be caulked). Or get however wide, ~3", and custom cut it, which isn't fun.

Comment: @Mazura Ha. Yes. Can totally understand the logic to just let it be. The problem is however that I have a problem with a mouldy smell coming into the kitchen when there is a breeze. I've tried treating it with bleach and methylated sprits, no luck. Anyway, I ended up answering my question. I tapped off the battens with a chisel. Turns out they were plastic battens fastened with small galvanised nails. Removed the panel. Bottom of the stud is totally rotten. So many things have been done incorrectly with this window install. Window is just sitting on top of the kitchen bench. No flashing!